# dart freezed @Default doesn't apply defaultValue on JsonKey

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

I have a class called `Player` (`player.dart`) that has a field called `isCaptain`:

```dart
@JsonKey(name: "is_captain") @Default(false) bool isCaptain,
```

The line above produces the following in `player.g.dart`:

```dart
isCaptain: json['is_captain'] as bool,
```

When I create a `Player` object using `Player.fromJson(playerJson)` that's missing the `is_captain` key, `isCaptain` is set to `null` on the `Player` object instead of `false` as provided by `@Default`.

When I add `defaultValue: false` to the `@JsonKey(...)` as follows:

```dart
@JsonKey(name: "is_captain", defaultValue: false) @Default(false) bool isCaptain,
```

...the implementation in `player.g.dart` changes to:

```dart
isCaptain: json['is_captain'] as bool? ?? false,
```

Now everything works as expected and if `is_captain` is not present in the API response, `isCaptain` gets the default value of `false`.

I'm confused because [freezed's documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#default-values) says that adding `@Default` automatically adds `defaultValue` to the `@JsonKey(...)` too but that doesn't seem to be the case here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freezed adds an implicit JsonKey with the default value.

Your issue is that you passed a custom JsonKey. In which case, your annotation takes over what Freezed auto-generates.

So by specifying a JsonKey, you basically removed the implicit default value added by Freezed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Rémi!